# Get Menus In Header.php FIle

Tags: menus

Hello Im Very Beginner In WordPress.
and im try to get menus in home page but it was not display as per the html theme.

It Was My Code..

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-wil" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <div class="top-menu">
    <nav class="menu menu--francisco">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-menu">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav menu__list">
                <li class="menu__item menu__item--current"><a href="index.html" class="menu__link"><span class="menu__helper">Home</span></a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a href="about.html" class="menu__link"><span class="menu__helper">About Us</span></a></li>                                      
                <li class="menu__item"><a href="gallery.html" class="menu__link"><span class="menu__helper">Departments</span></a></li>
                <li class="menu__item"><a href="contact.html" class="menu__link"><span class="menu__helper">Contact Us</span></a></li>

                <!--<li>
                    <?php
                    /*$defaults = array(
                                'theme_location' => 'top', 
                                'container' => '', 
                                'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav menu__list', 
                                'menu' => 'Header Menu');
                    wp_nav_menu($defaults);*/
                    ?>  
                </li> -->
            </ul>
        </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

but not display as per html code in the theme.
Pls Help ME Out For That.

thanks in Advance.
[image]

Comment: The `wp_nav_menu()` function will output your menu.  In this case, the menu named Header Menu.  But it will do nothing if commented out like shown.  `/* this code is skipped */`

Comment: sorry, do not understood..

Comment: how to put get menu code in html format?

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about having WordPress CMS menus appear correctly, your code would be edited as follows:

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse nav-wil" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <div class="top-menu">
        <nav class="menu menu--francisco">
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-menu">

          <?php
            $defaults = array(
              'theme_location' => 'top', 
              'container' => '', 
              'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav menu__list', 
              'menu' => 'Header Menu'
            );
            wp_nav_menu($defaults); ?> 

            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Assuming `register_nav_menu` was used to register a "top" location, this will display the Header Menu in that location.

Your code displays both static HTML and commented out PHP, however.  I may have completely misunderstood your question.  Please rephrase it or add more information if so.

Full documentation on WordPress menu usage can be found in the Codex:

`wp_nav_menu()`:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

`register_nav_menu()`: 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_nav_menu/